# Is it possible to sell an application that require Adobe Air runtime [license]?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, adobe, licensing

It's about the license.

I've created a prototype app which using `Adobe` Air runtime.

but, Before further development. 
i want to know is it breaking the AdobeAir license if i sell my app to the client ?

i found this link http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/android-licensing-native-extensions.html
but i think it's useless.

the closest answer i can get is here http://www.adobe.com/products/air/faq.html . 
Unfortunately, there's no 'selling' part.

Comment: This question is off topic as it is about legal issues, not about a programming problem. Ask the vendor and/or a lawyer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can develop commercial apps and sell it without any license issues. You should not obtain any special license for this purpose.

EDIT:

Just to add for clarity. You can distribute your app without any special license, or the app with captive runtime. However, you cannot distribute separate AIR runtime in some cases (for example, when you distribute your app via your website), but you can include separate AIR runtime file if you distribute your app offline (for example, via DVD)

More [here](http://www.adobe.com/products/air/faq.html#licensing)